# Fit image to outtermost div, fit div containing image to image

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have an image element, I need it to fit inside a specific div (let's call it div 1). The image has a wrapper div that needs to fit to the image (let's call it div 2).

It almost works using the following methods: 
setting the image and div 2 to float: left;
or 
setting image to display: block, and div 2 to display: inline-block.

Both work great when the page is first loaded, but div 1 is actually a fluid width/height div that resizes with the browser, and when you reduce the height of the browser the width of div 2 doesn't adjust (illustrated by the green border)

Here are sample pages:
http://sabrinagelbart.com/fit-img-and-outer-div-to-container.html 
(left:-50%, left:50% are for centering, don't make a difference with the bug)
http://sabrinagelbart.com/fit-img-and-outer-div-to-container-inline-block.html

Answer (score 0):

Try background-size: cover; and top: 0;, bottom: 0;
or try position: fixed;